# Can I have the same Apple ID in my iPhone and my iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-appstore, apple-id

How can I have de same Apple ID in my iPhone and my iPad (so that I can use the apps on iPad that I have in iPhone and "vice versa")

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are looking for here. The name of your phone is not related to your Apple ID, so are you looking to change the name of your phone or do you want to log in with the same Apple ID on both devices?

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can. Go into Settings and find the following tabs:

- iTunes and App Store
- iCloud

Then just log in with your Apple ID. They must be same in iPhone and iPad in order to share app purchases.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use one Apple ID among all of your Apple ID devices. In rear cases you will need separate Apple ID accounts when you need to separate contacts or other private info. In this case you should use different Apple ID in Settings > iCloud, but still use the same Apple ID for purchasing content in App Store and iTunes Store on both devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you had your iPad first then before you do go into settings>iCloud scroll down>find my iPad and turn it off.
If you had your iPhone first do the same thing but go on find my iPhone and turn that off.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean login app store with the same Apple ID and password  for app installation? Sure you can, and actually the app you have installed on your iPad can be directly sync to your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to only use **one** Apple ID since it becomes confusing by having two Apple ID's. Especially since you would have two buy each App twice.